# How to push route in history using redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, redux-saga, html5-history

I'm using react, redux, saga and router v4.

I want to make a redirect inside my saga, but I don't know how to access the `history` object, since I'm using the `BrowserRouter`.

What I want to do would look similar to:

```
export function * callWS (action) {
   const result = yield call(data, ws)

   if (result.status === 201) {
          yield call(history.push, '/success')
   }
}
```

But, since I'm using `BrowserRouter`, I never created this `history` object.
Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: If you are using `react-router-redux` in your app you can `put` `replace` action imported from this package.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and I came up with this solution..

in your `app.js` create the history and export it:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createHistory();
// ...
export { history };
```

Then in your sagas you can create a `forwardTo` function that handles navigation:

```
import { call, fork, takeLatest, cancel, take } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { history } from 'app';

function* myFunction() {
  try {
    // do something
    yield call(forwardTo, '/');
  } catch(e){
    // Do something
  }
}

export default function* defaultSaga() {
  const submitWatcher = yield fork(takeLatest, SOMETHING, submitForm);
   yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
   yield cancel(submitWatcher);
 }

function forwardTo(location) {
 history.push(location);
}
```